# The "more (..)" link shouldn't make me scroll through stuff I've already seen

Tags: feature-request, design, footer

There was a change to the footer and after clicking it thrice, I've already found one thing that I consider a major pain point:

When I click the "more (..)" entry in one of the Stack Exchange categories, I get redirected to the https://stackexchange.com/sites#category site, where an ajax-request fetches the very same content I just viewed and presents it to me again...

Guess what's at the top? Right... all the sites I've already discarded as not relevant... That's wasting my time and makes for a bad experience.

Why is there a "more (..)" link in the first place?

The only thing it "provides" is a click more that is not even needed in the first place.. There is a succinct categorization for these sites, and there is enough space to actually fit each category into the footer completely on my display, even more: to fit each category completely into the space allotted by the design.

Also... what determines which sites are "privileged enough" to be fully featured in the footer and which sites are hidden behind "more (..)"?

Comment: To answer the last paragraph: mostly graduation status, with some caching and randomness in the mix.